# Billingsley Probability and Measure Section 3.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading section 3 of the Billingsley book. On page 38, we have this:

[image]

My question is: why is 3.5 true because of finite subadditivity? I thought that finite subadditivity implied that for $B_1$, $B_2$ we must have $P(B_1 \cup B_2) \le P(B_1) + P(B_2)$. So I don't see how 3.5 follows. In fact, it seems to me that the inequality sign should go the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not that (3.5) is true, but rather that it is equivalent to (3.4). And this is so because the inequality 
$$P^*(A \cap E) + P^*(A^c \cap E) \geq P^*(E)$$
is immediate from finite subadditivity, as you suspected.

The upshot is that in proving that a set is measurable, it suffices to check (3.5).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. So basically, we always have $\ge$. So as long as we can show that something is $\le$, then we know equality holds!

Comment: @Genetics Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not said that 3.5 is true because of finite subadditivity.

Observed is that $$P^*(A\cap E)+P^*(A^{\complement}\cap E)\geq P^*(E)$$ **will always hold** because of finite subadditivity.

So that inequality is not relevant anymore if it comes to checking that:  $$P^*(A\cap E)+P^*(A^{\complement}\cap E)= P^*(E)$$

It is enough to check: $$P^*(A\cap E)+P^*(A^{\complement}\cap E)\leq P^*(E)$$